# JavaScript console.log of datepicker and counting difference between two dates doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm struggling to get a console.log of two dates as well as the days between those two days.

[image]

This is the JavaScript part:

```
var startDate;
var endDate;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    startDate = j("#startTime").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        onSelect: function() {
            console.log("Test1");
        }
    });

    endDate = j("#endTime").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        onSelect: function() {
            console.log("Test2");
        }
    });
});


function createSpots(){
    var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

    const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
    const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((startDate - endDate) / oneDay));

    console.log("diffDays: " + diffDays);
    console.log("startDate: " + startDate);
    console.log("endDate: " + endDate.dateFormat);
    console.log("Spots created!");
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<script src="/tools/Scripts/apps/Win10Rollout/AutomatedSpots.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<p>Startdatum:<input id="startTime" type="text" class="hasDatepicker"/></p>
<p>Enddatum:<input id="endTime" type="text" class="hasDatepicker"/></p> 
<p>Spots: 
   <textarea id="text" name="text" cols="35" rows="4"></textarea> </p> 
<p>Anzahl Einträge je Spot:<input type="number" id="spot"/></p> 
<button onclick="createSpots()" type="button" id="button">Erstellen</button>
```

The console says `startDate: [object Object]`.
When I use `startDate.getDate()` it says `Uncaught TypeError: startDate.getDate is not a function`. Using `startDate.dateFormat` doesn't work either.

To count the difference between those dates I used

```
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((startDate - endDate) / oneDay));
```

but here it says `diffDays: NaN`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `startDate` is a jQuery object not a Date object. Use the [jQuery UI datepicker getDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) as documented

Comment: I am not sure if the `datepicker` method returning a number. It is probably returning a string (as specified `dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'`).

Comment: @charlietfl I tried `currentStartDate = j( "#startTime" ).datepicker( "getDate" );`, but it says that `currentStartDate` is null

Comment: Should work fine when used after datepicker is initialized and date is changed. Any errors in dev tools console?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the note, it showed a jQuery bug and I fixed that now. It works now, but I still can't calculate the difference as it shows `diffDays` as NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript to be able to use `console.log()` with objects and to get the details out of this objects, you can either avoid concatenating the object to string so you can use

`console.log("startDate: ", startDate);` instead of using `console.log("startDate: " + startDate);`

or you can stringify the object by using `JSON.stringify`, so it will be as follows:

`console.log("startDate: " + JSON.stringify(startDate));`

However `startDate` variable in your case, this is a JQuery object so if you are going to log it, it will log the html object so in your case to log the value inside the `startDate` object, you can use the following:

```
console.log("startDate: " , startDate[0].value);
```

Regarding the calculation of the date differences you can do the following:

```
  function createSpots(){
        var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
        const startDateValue = new Date(startDate[0].value);
        const endDateValue = new Date(endDate[0].value);
        const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds

        const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((startDateValue - endDateValue) / oneDay));

        console.log("diffDays: " + diffDays);
        console.log("startDate: " , startDateValue);

        console.log("endDate: " + endDateValue);
        console.log("Spots created!");
    }
```

Simply you will need to get the values input from the user then convert those values to date object using `new Date()` then you can use your formula normally.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Can you also tell me how to get the difference between 2 dates because `diffDays` is still NaN if I use `const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((startDate[0].value - endDate[0].value) / oneDay));`

Comment: It is not an *html object* it is a jQuery object. No such thing as an *html object*

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are correct I will update the answer

Comment: @PoliticsStudent I have updated the answer to include the date difference calculation.

Comment: @Karim Thank you for your effort, but I still get a NaN. I can now get the values with `currentStartDate = j("#startTime").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd,MM,yyyy' }).val();` but the problem with the difference between days is there as well

Comment: @PoliticsStudent were you able to convert it to date object using `const sDate = new Date(currentStartDate)` or what was the result of new Date()?

Comment: @Karim No, it says `Invalid Date`. I think it has something to do with the Date format, because I have to use DD.MM.YYYY

Comment: I used ` const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((currentStartDate.getTime() - currentEndDate.getTime()) / oneDay));` and it works now.  Thank you for your help! :)